# rosdoc fuerte python ValueError

Tags: ros, ubuntu, ros-fuerte, ubuntu-precise, rosdoc

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey all,

after upgrading to ubuntu precise and ros fuerte I have problems when running rosdoc.
I always get the error paste below.

Any idea what to do?

Tinne

fiep@Fiep /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/documentation/rosdoc $ ./rosdoc geometric_semantics
/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/documentation/rosdoc/src/rosdoc/rdcore.py:43: UserWarning: roslib.rospack is deprecated, please use rospkg
import roslib.rospack
initializing rosdoc context:
package filters: ['geometric_semantics']
path filters: []
+package[geometric_semantics]
+stack[geometric_relations_semantics]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/documentation/rosdoc/src/rosdoc/**init**.py", line 134, in main
artifacts = generate_docs(ctx)
File "/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/documentation/rosdoc/src/rosdoc/**init**.py", line 83, in generate_docs
import doxygenator
File "/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/documentation/rosdoc/src/rosdoc/doxygenator.py", line 334, in 
header_template = load_tmpl(header_template_name())
File "/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/documentation/rosdoc/src/rosdoc/doxygenator.py", line 199, in header_template_name
major, minor, patch = doxygen_version.split('.')
ValueError: too many values to unpack

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/34020/rosdoc-fuerte-python-valueerror/) by [Tinne De Laet](https://answers.ros.org/users/137/tinne-de-laet/) on ROS Answers with karma: 198 on 2012-05-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) on 2012-05-15**:
Given the error message, can you post your Doxygen version number by running the command-line option?

**Comment by [Tinne De Laet](https://answers.ros.org/users/137/tinne-de-laet/) on 2012-05-16**:
doxygen --version: 1.7.6.1

**Comment by [Tinne De Laet](https://answers.ros.org/users/137/tinne-de-laet/) on 2012-05-22**:
python -- version: Python 2.7.3

**Comment by [Tinne De Laet](https://answers.ros.org/users/137/tinne-de-laet/) on 2012-05-22**:
Just to inform you that one of my colleagues, Steven, is able to run rosdoc for the same package on his computer.
He also has ros fuerte and python 2.7.3.
He however has doxygen 1.7.5 and compiled ros-fuerte-documentation from source.

**Comment by [Tinne De Laet](https://answers.ros.org/users/137/tinne-de-laet/) on 2012-05-22**:
Just to inform you that one of my colleagues, Steven, is able to run the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found out what is causing the problems.
Apparently rosdoc was never used before with a doxygen version containing a build number (i.e. major.minor.patch.build).
I adapted the source of rosdoc to cover the extra build number in the doxygen version.

I filed a bug in trac and also submitted the patch there (https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/ticket/5451).

## Patch:
Index: doxygenator.py

--- doxygenator.py      (revision 16732)
+++ doxygenator.py      (working copy)
@@ -196,7 +196,7 @@
# doxygen not available
if doxygen_version is None:
return None

- major, minor, patch = doxygen_version.split('.')

- major, minor, patch, build = doxygen_version.split('.')

  ## > 1.7.3 doxygen changed the template syntax

  if int(major) > 1 or int(minor) > 7 or int(patch) > 3:
  return 'header-1.7.4.html'

Tinne

---

Originally posted by [Tinne De Laet](https://answers.ros.org/users/137/tinne-de-laet/) with karma: 198 on 2012-05-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tinne De Laet](https://answers.ros.org/users/137/tinne-de-laet/) on 2012-05-23**:
This patch does not work if you have a doxygen version not containing the build number. Improved patch available here: https://code.ros.org/trac/ros/ticket/3969.

**Comment by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) on 2012-05-29**:
Patch applied to source, thanks